# Eclipse - Java Code Assist - Не подставляет public-переменные класса

Tags: java, eclipse

Всем привет. Чтобы не писать много букв, привожу такой скрин:

[image: Eclipse - Java Code Assist]

После выбора метода "Mjx.me" Code Assist подставляет переменные (опция Insert parameter names):

```
Mjx.me(ax, ax, ax, dx, ex);
```

Первая переменная - ок, берет из метода *en(int ax)*.

Четвертая и пятая переменные - тоже ок, подставляет public-переменные класса.

Вторая и третья переменные (bx и cx) - ожидаю, что возьмет соответствующие из переменных класса, но, как видно, этого не происходит (используется одна и та же переменная ax).

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как заставить Code Assist автоматически рисовать

Mjx.me(ax, **bx, cx,** dx, ex);

вместо

Mjx.me(ax, **ax, ax,** dx, ex);